# facebook says thumbnail 250x250 image is too small

Tags: html, facebook

On http://www.stanuu.org/shall_we_gather.html

I have:

```
<link rel="image_src" href="http://www.stanuu.org/j_cherry_fb.jpg"><br>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.stanuu.org/j_cherry_fb.jpg">
```

(I omitted the "<" and ">" because it's late, this is my first post, my wife is yammering at me and I can't figure out how to tell the editor it's HTML. Each line starts with one and ends with the other.)

`j_cherry_fb.jpg` is 250x250.

Facebook debugger tells me:

> Provided og:image is not big enough. Please use an image that's at least 200x200 px. Image 'http://www.stanuu.org/images/j_cherry_s2.jpg' will be used instead.

I started with a 160x160 for j_cherry.fb, got the error above, cropped and padded a 180x240 to be 200x200, then padded it to 250x250. Any ideas?

The basic problem is that I use portrait mode 180x240 pictures of our minister, and every time I post a link FB cuts off the top of his head to make it square. So I spent 30 minutes reading about og: and Link rel and thought I had it nailed.

`j_cherry_s2.jpg` is 180x240.

I REALLY don't want to start using square pictures on my web pages just to make FB happy.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget that Facebook probably cached your image. So if you no matter how you changed it, Facebook still has the old copy. Have you tried changing the name of the image? To bypass the cache?

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="image_src" href="http://www.stanuu.org/images/j_cherry_s2.jpg" />
```

should work fine, keep 2 things in mind. 1 the picture you use for your thumbnail does not need to be seen by the public, it can be just used as a meta. 2 the facebook debugger is bugged. I would put the code in the HEAD section and do a few tests after it has had a change to propagate.

Comment: I KNEW it was late. Thanks!

Comment: @TedPack let me know how it works out for ya, I have done it in the past and its a fun toy to play with :-)

Comment: It worked perfectly after I added the subdirectory. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook really caches those images so when you actually do change the dimensions make sure you do something like this and then try the debugger.

```
<link rel="image_src" href="http://www.stanuu.org/images/j_cherry_s2.jpg?v=1" />
```